# Confused with the property MAXCHANNELS functionality from WMQ

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i did a test with the MQ property **`MAXCHANNELS`** from QMGR's qm.ini but got the result which i don't understand, please see my WMQ environment detail as below:

OS: Windows 7
MQ: 7.0.1.3

MaxChannels configuration:
[image]

MQSC `dis chs(*)` whose total number is **5**
[image]

That's my confusion. According to the description from MQ inforcenter, that **MAXCHANNELS** means the maximum number of channels that can be current (including server-connection channels with connected clients). However, my config value is **1** while the number of current active ones gets be 5 already. BTW, i did the qmgr restart after value reset. Why does it happen? From the point of my view, some error like reaching the max number should be shown in the error.log. But i don't see anything. Everything seems working fine.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: @T.Rob would you please help answer this question? Thanks

Comment: I don't have a good answer.  It is not working as documented but then MAXCHANNELS=1 is such an unusual (some would say radical) configuration there may be a boundary condition there that either escaped testing or the doc writers didn't think to cover it.  Or maybe its a bug but if so I haven't been able to duplicate it.  I would suggest sending feedback from the Infocenter page or open a PMR. (If you open a PMR, feel free to email the number to me so I can follow along.)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility for this not taking effect is that you may be updating the configuration in the wrong location.

In MQ 7.0.1.x the queue manager configuration could instead be held in a qm.ini file, for example if its configured as multi-instance. From MQ 7.1 onwards the qm.ini is the location that all distributed queue managers keep their configuration data.

If the queue manager is using ini files then the following stanza should be added instead to qm.ini, which can be found in the queue manager data directory;

```
Channels:
    MaxChannels=1
```

Thanks, Jon

Comment: but for windows platform, such qm config has been stored within registry which i also provided in my question post. Do you think i did the wrong config there?